# How do I stop my input field from defocusing on each keystroke? (React / NextJS / SWR / Optimistic Data / Tailwind)

Tags: reactjs, forms, next.js, tailwind-css, swr

I have the following input:

```
<input
                className="accent-carnation-500 block w-full text-sm text-gray-900 bg-transparent rounded-lg border-1 border-gray-300 appearance-none dark:text-white dark:border-gray-600 dark:focus:border-blue-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 focus:border-carnation-600 peer"
                type="text"
                name="name"
                id={"lineItem" + item.name}
                value={item.name}
                onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, index)}
              />
```

Here is my handleChange function:

```
async function handleChange(e, index) {
    const updatedLineItems = [...lineItemsArray];
    updatedLineItems[index][e.target.name] = e.target.value;

    const updatedQuote = {
      ...quote,
      lineItems: {
        ...lineItems,
        lineItemsArray: updatedLineItems,
      },
    };

    try {
      await mutate(updateLineItem(updatedQuote), {
        optimisticData: {
          ...quote,
          lineItems: {
            ...lineItems,
            lineItemsArray: [
              ...lineItemsArray.slice(0, index),
              {
                ...lineItemsArray[index],
                [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
              },
              ...lineItemsArray.slice(index + 1),
            ],
          },
        },
        rollbackOnError: true,
        populateCache: true,
        revalidate: false,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error updating line item:", error);
      alert("Error updating line item");
    }
  }
```

For the most part, it is working as intended. The data updates immediately and the ui is updated when I add or delete a character from the input field. However, after one keystroke the input loses focus and I have to either click it again or press tab to target it before typing another keystroke. There is no delay (i.e. if I rapidly click and press a key it will update without error), so I'm just looking to stop the defocus.

Tried adding debounce to the entire function - this just created a large delay in the input.

Expecting to be able to type as much as I need to without defocus.

Comment: I don’t know react that well, I use vue mostly. But the behavior usually comes from rerendering the input. I think you bind the id of the input to the value of the input. So the id of the input element changes on every keystroke. This may trigger a rerender, because there is a difference between the shadow DOM and the DOM. Try it without `item.name` in the id of the input.